# proxy in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, proxy, wlan

[image]

### Proxy server

> In computer networking, a proxy server is a server application or appliance that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from servers that provide those resources. A proxy server thus functions on behalf of the client when requesting service, potentially masking the true origin of the request to the resource server.

I want to know that if I set the proxy `automatic` than will it work for wlan0/wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* the `Xisilon.Xyz` network has a proxy available, *and* the network administrator has set up the [proxy auto-discovery information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) correctly, then yes, the web browser(s) and any HTTP/HTTPS features of your Kali desktop environment should use that proxy if you set that setting to `Automatic`.

The proxy may still be set to require authentication before it can be used.

Note that you would then be using the proxy that is under the network administrator's control, and that proxy will most likely log the real IP address of any incoming connections, so you cannot really mask the origin of your requests from the administrator that way.

Also, if you install a proxy software to your Kali system, that won't mask you either, because the source IP address of any outgoing connections from the proxy on your Kali system is still going to be the IP address of the Kali system.